# Magento 2 how to get product id from QuoteDetailsItemInterface object

Tags: magento2, tax, quoteitem, interface

I am using Magento 2.1.5 . I am trying to get product id in tax apply function `calculateWithTaxNotInPrice` is below

```
 /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function calculateWithTaxNotInPrice(QuoteDetailsItemInterface $item, $quantity, $round = true)
    {
        $taxRateRequest = $this->getAddressRateRequest()->setProductClassId(
            $this->taxClassManagement->getTaxClassId($item->getTaxClassKey())
        );


        //want to get product id here from item object but its give null value
        var_dump($item->getProductId());exit;


        $rate = $this->calculationTool->getRate($taxRateRequest);
        $appliedRates = $this->calculationTool->getAppliedRates($taxRateRequest);

        $applyTaxAfterDiscount = $this->config->applyTaxAfterDiscount($this->storeId);
        $discountAmount = $item->getDiscountAmount();
        $discountTaxCompensationAmount = 0;

        // Calculate $rowTotal
        $price = $this->calculationTool->round($item->getUnitPrice());
        $rowTotal = $price * $quantity;
        $rowTaxes = [];
        $rowTaxesBeforeDiscount = [];
        $appliedTaxes = [];
        //Apply each tax rate separately
        foreach ($appliedRates as $appliedRate) {
            $taxId = $appliedRate['id'];
            $taxRate = $appliedRate['percent'];
            $rowTaxPerRate = $this->calculationTool->calcTaxAmount($rowTotal, $taxRate, false, false);
            $deltaRoundingType = self::KEY_REGULAR_DELTA_ROUNDING;
            if ($applyTaxAfterDiscount) {
                $deltaRoundingType = self::KEY_TAX_BEFORE_DISCOUNT_DELTA_ROUNDING;
            }
            $rowTaxPerRate = $this->roundAmount($rowTaxPerRate, $taxId, false, $deltaRoundingType, $round, $item);
            $rowTaxAfterDiscount = $rowTaxPerRate;

            //Handle discount
            if ($applyTaxAfterDiscount) {
                //TODO: handle originalDiscountAmount
                $taxableAmount = max($rowTotal - $discountAmount, 0);
                $rowTaxAfterDiscount = $this->calculationTool->calcTaxAmount(
                    $taxableAmount,
                    $taxRate,
                    false,
                    false
                );
                $rowTaxAfterDiscount = $this->roundAmount(
                    $rowTaxAfterDiscount,
                    $taxId,
                    false,
                    self::KEY_REGULAR_DELTA_ROUNDING,
                    $round,
                    $item
                );
            }
            $appliedTaxes[$taxId] = $this->getAppliedTax(
                $rowTaxAfterDiscount,
                $appliedRate
            );

            $rowTaxes[] = $rowTaxAfterDiscount;
            $rowTaxesBeforeDiscount[] = $rowTaxPerRate;
        }
        $rowTax = array_sum($rowTaxes);
        $rowTaxBeforeDiscount = array_sum($rowTaxesBeforeDiscount);
        $rowTotalInclTax = $rowTotal + $rowTaxBeforeDiscount;
        $priceInclTax = $rowTotalInclTax / $quantity;
        if ($round) {
            $priceInclTax = $this->calculationTool->round($priceInclTax);
        }

        return $this->taxDetailsItemDataObjectFactory->create()
            ->setCode($item->getCode())
            ->setType($item->getType())
            ->setRowTax($rowTax)
            ->setPrice($price)
            ->setPriceInclTax($priceInclTax)
            ->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
            ->setRowTotalInclTax($rowTotalInclTax)
            ->setDiscountTaxCompensationAmount($discountTaxCompensationAmount)
            ->setAssociatedItemCode($item->getAssociatedItemCode())
            ->setTaxPercent($rate)
            ->setAppliedTaxes($appliedTaxes);
    }
```

In above code `QuoteDetailsItemInterface $item` have no product id method in interface `Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterface`

Can anyone suggest me how to include product id method in interface?

I have also add method in interface  `Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterface` as below

```
 public function getProductId();

 public function setProductId($productId);
```

Also I have define same method in model `Magento/Tax/Model/Sales/Quote/ItemDetails` as below

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getProductId()
{
    return $this->getData('product_id');
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setProductId($productId)
{
    return $this->getData('product_id',$productId);
}
```

But it's not working.

Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Use `$item->getProduct()->getId()`

Comment: @AnkitShah it is not working, it gives error `Call to a member function getId() on null `

Comment: Also $item->getId() is not working

Comment: The ItemDetails class that you are using will not be able to provide you with product id as it does not contain it. You need to use the Quote object (which you can easily get from checkout session) to get Items. That items will reveal the product Id.

can you post the actual function in which you are calling the above function "calculateWithTaxNotInPrice"

Comment: @PankajBhope i am not using that function anywhere but as off now i am directly trying to get product id in that function. You are right i can get item from quote but i want to apply tax according to product attribute. Suppose in cart have 3 items so how can i get known for which product i am applying tax?

Comment: ok. But as if now from what I understand is you need product ids right. If yes, I am posting a snippet that should help you to get the product ids.

Comment: okay, i need to apply tax on product vise according to product attribute

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterface` interface, you'll see the following 2 methods:

```
/**
 * Get code (sku or shipping code)
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getCode();


/**
 * Get type (e.g., shipping, product, wee, gift wrapping, etc.)
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getType();
```

So I'm assuming that if you try `$item->getCode()` in combination with the `getType()`-method in combination with a product resource, you're ready to go.

Example:

```
class Example
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product
     */
    protected $productResource;

    /**
     * Example constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\ProductFactory $productResourceFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\ProductFactory $productResourceFactory
    ) {
        $this->productResource = $productResourceFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterface $item
     * @return false|int
     */
    public function getProductIdFromQuoteDetailsItem(\Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterface $item)
    {
        if ($item->getType() === 'product') {
            return $this->productResource->getIdBySku($item->getCode());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

In this example, the method `getProductIdFromQuoteDetailsItem()` will return either the ID or `false` of no ID can be found for the SKU (this can be the case if the product has been deleted after the quote has been created). Haven't tried it out, but if I'm only referring to the service contracts this should work.

Answer (score 0):

1) Inject the checkout session in your constructor.

2) here is code to get items:

```
$items = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote->getAllItems();

foreach ($items as $item)
{
   $productId = $item->getProductId();
   /** here you can add your logic, what you want to achieve by using product id.
    *
    */

   /** if you are not getting other information regarding 
    *  product in items data, you can use following code
    * $product = $item->getProduct();
    */    
}
```